# How do you call the escaped hex code notation

Tags: unicode, ascii

The escaped hex code for characters.

where you have \x and then the hex code for the ascii character.
like '\x48'

how do you call it ?

and is there an online tool for converting it to text ?

like for example by using python:

```
s = '\x48\x49'
s
'HI'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using firefox or chrome, they can turn it into a text if you just copypaste a string like `'\x48\x49'` to the their console. But you could also use this http://jsfiddle.net/HHfdp/show/

They are called hexadecimal escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

It probably goes by a few names, but a "hexadecimal escape" is fine.

You can find out more about these in the [Python documentation for String Literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).